# Integer conversion to long in assignment contexts

Tags: java, type-conversion, assignment-operator

I'm confused about how Java works with long and int...

Take following code:

```
long l1 = 0xFF00000000000000L;
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(l1));
l1 = 15;
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(l1));
```

I assume that with the line

```
l1 = 15;
```

the number 15 defaults to an int, hence only 32 bits will be copied to the l1 variable and that it would not affect the higher 32-bits of the long variable.

In other words I would expect the output to be

```
ff00000000000000
ff0000000000000f
```

Instead, I get

```
ff00000000000000
f
```

Why?

Comment: Why do you assume that assining a **new** value to a variable will keep part of the **old** value?

Comment: You assigned a value of `15` to variable, and you expected it to have a value of `-72057594037927921`?!

Comment: Sound like you are comming from Cobol?

Comment: I think the simplest way to copy the 32 bits of an `int` into a `long` is `longVal = longVal & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L | intVal & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFL`.

Comment: Indeed, a silly question from me, thing is just that as I thought that constant numbers default to int.... 
I thought:

 l1 = 15L 

 --> 64 bits are assigned, and with

 l1 = 15  

--> only 32 bits are assigned as 15 defaults to an int type).


But apparently not. What is purpose then of using the L suffix?

Comment: @ChrisPeeters `15L` is a `long` whereas `15` is an `int`. When you write `long a = 15;`, the `int` is being widened to a `long`. You need the `L` when the literal is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (e.g. `long a = 3000000000;` won't compile), and you need the `L` in `Long a = 15L`.

Answer (score 1):

With `l1 = 15;` the number `15` is interpreted as the `long` representing `15` whose bits are `000000000000000f`. `15` is casted to `long` type since you are assigningi t to a `long. When printed this results in`f`.

Answer (score 1):

You define `l1` to be a `long`, so if you do an assignment, there will always a complete `long` be assigned.

In the case where you try to assign an `int` the int will first get converted to a `long` and then assigned. The conversion is an actual conversion, so the additional bits are set to zero (or whatever is needed to represent the original number as a long).

In most cases Java hides the details of memory management completely from the developer. So the effects as you describe aren't really part of a java developers life.

What you intended could be done with bitwise operators. I hardly ever use them, but this might work:

```
l1 = (l1 & 0xffffffff00000000L) | 15
```

Comment: The additional bits are set to zero is a bit misleading as they are set to 1 if the int is negative. Obviously that's not the case here, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @PaulBoddington correct.

Answer (score 0):

15 int is changed to 15 long before the assignment. Java will do that for you to stop you from getting terrible bugs. Imagine if you assigned number 15 int to a long and you got a different number simply because you did not realize you assigned an into to a long.

Comment: indeed. Even with an explicit cast: l1 = (int) 15;
I still get the same results
is there no way to copy only the first 32 -bits?

Comment: @ChrisPeeters it is possible by doing bitwise manipulations: l1 = (l1 & ffffffff00000000) | 15 might do what you are looking for.